# On click function to toggleClass exclude click on children

Tags: jquery

Basically trying to remove/toggle the 'active' class from the div, but if I click inside the children of 'parent-div' the function happens as well, and it should only work on the parent-div. It's a fixed background that should act as "click outside to close" function, and I can't disable clicking inside the children because there is a form inside in them.

Tried event.stopPropagation as well but that didn't do anything.

HTML

```
<div class="ims-search active">
  <div class="ims-search-content">
    <div class=ims-search-input">
      <form>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
$(".ims-search").click(function(event){
    if (!$(event.target).is('.ims-search .active')){
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    }
});
```

Comment: Please include the relevant html

Comment: `.is(".class1 .class2")` is a selector, so should probably be `.is(".class1.class2")` if you're checking if parent is active, rather than if active is a child of parent.

Comment: Included the HTML.

I tried as a selector, or just the class in general without the '.active' but it didn't work, the function was the issue because the class is used only here.

Comment: For `.stopPropagation` you *could* do something like `$(".ims-search *").click(function(event) { event.stopPropagation(); })` - but seems a bit hacky TBH.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can compare `event.target === event.currentTarget` to see if the element clicked is the one the event is assigned to.

Events bubble up: `.target` will match the actually clicked element, while `.currentTarget` will match the selector / element the event is assigned to.

Giving:

```js
$(".parent-div").click(function(event) {
  if (event.target === event.currentTarget) 
    $(this).hide();
});
```

```css
.parent-div { height:150px; width:150px; border:1px solid blue; position:relative; }
#inner { left:50px;top:50px;height:50px;width:50px; background-color: pink; position:relative; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent-div">
 <div id="inner">
  don't click here
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you so much! I don't know how I missed .currentTarget.